# what paramter must be used to pass the path of class file to be executed in java code

Tags: java, shell

```
  java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
 -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
 "input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
 $OPTIONS
```

**As mention above,I have this java code embed inside shell code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper
FILE=/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/config/logging.properties

export HH_CLASSPATH=.:/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:.:$BASEDIR/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar
#JAVA_VERSION="$(java -version)"            
export JAVA_VERSION
export TEST_FILE=$BASEDIR/TestData/TestDataV7118.txt
export OPTIONS=1

  java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
 -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
 "input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
 $OPTIONS


export BASEDIR=""
export HH_CLASSPATH=""
export TEST_FILE=""
export OPTIONS=""
```

So I need to run this file but i want to know what parameter to use for providing the class file:
  **Home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP**

as it is giving the error:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP
```

Is there any parameter i might be missing before providing the class to be executed.

If i am replacing -classpath with -jar:

```
  java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
  -jar "$HH_CLASSPATH" /home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper   /dist/com/mmm/cms/homehealth/test/HomeHealthGrouper_HP.class\
  "input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
  $OPTIONS
```

It is giving the error:

**Error: Unable to access jarfile .:/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HomeHealthJava.jar:.:/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/HH_PPS_V_API.jar**

Comment: A sidenote, to be sure that you're not messing with built-in shell variables, make sure you use lower case identifiers for user defined variables, ie , `basedir` instead of `BASEDIR` and so.

Comment: I think that's not the problem its not loading any class from the beginning and i think that the path might needed to be passed in some other way or with some parameter.

Comment: I did not say that is the problem. I was just suggesting about a best practice that you should follow in shell scripting. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

The last argument of the java command would be the class to execute

Answer (score 0):

You specified main class as *home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP*. I think it is little mistake.

Instead add directory */home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/* to variable HH_CLASSPATH which is contains classpath and specify main class as *com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP*. And make shure that exists compilled class file */home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/com/mmm/cms/homehealth/test/HomeHealthGrouper_HP.class*. It must be *.class file, not *.java file. *.java files contains source code and *.class files contains compilled binary code.

Comment: You mean like this:           *export HH_CLASSPATH=.:/home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/:.:$BASEDIR/dist/
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
 -classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" /home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/com/mmm/cms/homehealth/test/HomeHealthGrouper_HP.class\
 "input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
  $OPTIONS*.    This one is giving error: **Error: Could not find or load main class .home.bitsbridge.Desktop.HPPP.HomeHealthGrouper.dist.com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP.class**

Comment: Not /home/bitsbridge/Desktop/HPPP/HomeHealthGrouper/dist/com/mmm‌​/cms/homehealth/test‌​/HomeHealthGrouper_H‌​P.class. Specify main class as com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the effort guys i figure it out:

```
 java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$FILE"\
-classpath "$HH_CLASSPATH" com.mmm.cms.homehealth.test.HomeHealthGrouper_HP\
"input=$TEST_FILE" "config=$BASEDIR/config/HomeHealthGrouper.properties"\
$OPTIONS
```

The problem was that the jar file inside classpath was extracted and i only need to remove the extracted folder and mention .jar file path in class path and .class file path after that in com.mms.... form.